# calling one user control from another user control's function in wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls

Good day to all.

I have one user control(uc1) in which i have a control(profilepic) for the image holding. I have another user control(uc2) which grabs images continuously from webcamera and it has some extended functionality also.( So only we have made that as another user control).

Now my question is how to attach the image taken from webcamera( uc2 control) to uc1 image control( i have lot many other controls in uc1) in one of the uc1 function say timer tick? Trying the below code

```
cw = new uc2();
this.Content = cw;
```

//this here is uc1, and with this uc2 occupies all space of uc1 blocking all other controls

is not fruitful.

```
cw = new uc2();
this.profilepic = cw.WebcamCtrl.TakeSnapshot();
```

//is giving error saying that return type does not match image type

is also not fruitful.

Can anyone suggest me the working code for this.

Thank you very much in advance.
Thanks,
Jagadeesh

Comment: The best way is to communicate via a ViewModel, with bindings, not by accessing the controls directly. That way you'll get much cleaner code, which is much easier to maintain and debug..

Comment: U can use a messaging library.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewModel for each Usercontrol and communicate between them via [Mediator Pattern](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/using-the-mediator-pattern-in-mvvm-wpf/)